# How to check if Db2 database is encrypted at rest?

Tags: db2, db2-luw

In Db2 v11.5.7 on Linux x86_64 I have configured keystore, updated dbm cfg and created database with "encrypt" command:

```
db2 "create database dbenc encrypt"
```

Database created successfully.

Now lets say I have two databases encrypted and non-encrypted database. How to check if database is encrypted and what encryption algorithms are used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get info if current database is encrypted:

```
db2 get db cfg for <db_name> | grep Encrypted
```

It returns: `Encrypted database = YES` if it is encrypted and `Encrypted database = No` it it is not.

Comment: You should accept your answer. It will inform readers that the answer solves the question